# How to automate Reactjs drop downs custom elements using Watir

Tags: reactjs, ruby, ruby-watir

```
<div class="MuiPaper-root MuiMenu-paper">
<ul class="MuiList-padding" role="listbox" tabindex="-1"  id="sort-by-menu-list" data-testid="sort-by-menu-list">
<li class="MuiButtonBase" data-value="HELDBY">option1</li>
<li class="MuiButtonBase" data-value="DATE_D">option2</li>
<li class="MuiButtonBase" data-value="DATE_A">option3</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

How do I pick an option?
I did try

```
@browser.element(id: "sort-by-menu-list").set("option1")
@browser.element(id: "sort-by-menu-list").send_keys :enter
```

none of them work